# Adding a node from tabItem to another tabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have multiple TabItems in my `TabControl`; `tabItem1`, `tabItem2`, `tabItem3`...these are `CloseableTabItem`.

If I add a node in `tabItem1` and press a button to make a subGraph model for this node, the same node should appear in `tabItem2`; so that

`tabItem2-Header = nodeName` and `nodeName = tabItem1-Header`.

The code work correct but the problem is that if I add a new node in `tabItem2` and press the subGraph-Button, the node will be added to `tabItem3` but the `nodeName = tabItem1-Header`.

I think I need to write in the `if()` beside to my first Condition another condition, but I don't know what condition will be suitable

```
MyNodeData todata = new MyNodeData();
if (tabItem1.IsLoaded)
{
  string childNodeName = (String)tabItem1.Header;
  todata.Text = childNodeName;
  return; 
}
if (tabItem2.IsLoaded) 
{
  string childNodeName = (String)tabItem2.Header;
  todata.Text = childNodeName;
  return;
}
if (tabItem3.IsLoaded)
{
  string childNodeName = (String)tabItem3.Header;
  todata.Text = childNodeName;
  return;
}
```